# VB Set Mail Priority High

Tags: vb.net, email, module

the code sends out the email and works okay but for some reason it is not going out as High importance. what am I doing wrong.

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail
Module SendMail
Sub SendMessage()
        Dim olApp As Object
        Dim olMail As Object
        Dim olNs As Object
        Dim Priority As MailPriority
    olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    With olMail
         olMail.To = "" '// Add recipient
         olMail.Cc = ""
         olMail.Bcc = ""
         olMail.Subject = "New File " 
         olMail.HTMLBody = "Your File is Ready " & Format(Now, "Long Date")
         olMail.Attachments.Add = " " '// Add attachments to the message.
         olMail.Priority = MailPriority.High '// High importance
         olMail.Send()
    End With
    olMail = Nothing
    olApp = Nothing
    olNs = Nothing
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: "On Error Resume Next"? *Really*? Your code to set the priority could be throwing an exception and you wouldn't know it.

Comment: The sender **never** sets high priority. It's up the receiver's email program to decide that. The property exists in outlook for setting messages in your own folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending using the System.Net.Mail namespace instead.

Example:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
    Function SendEmail(ByVal Recipients As List(Of String), _
                      ByVal FromAddress As String, _
                      ByVal Subject As String, _
                      ByVal Body As String, _
                      ByVal UserName As String, _
                      ByVal Password As String, _
                      Optional ByVal Server As String = "smtp.gmail.com", _
                      Optional ByVal Port As Integer = 587, _
                      Optional ByVal Attachments As List(Of String) = Nothing) As String
        Dim Email As New MailMessage()
        Try
            Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient
            For Each Attachment As String In Attachments
                Email.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Attachment))
            Next
            Email.From = New MailAddress(FromAddress)
            For Each Recipient As String In Recipients
                Email.To.Add(Recipient)
            Next
            Email.Subject = Subject
            Email.Body = Body
            '----------------------------------
            Email.Priority = MailPriority.High
            '----------------------------------
            SMTPServer.Host = Server
            SMTPServer.Port = Port
            SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
            SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
            SMTPServer.Send(Email)
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Email to " & Recipients(0) & " from " & FromAddress & " was sent."
        Catch ex As SmtpException
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Sending Email Failed. Smtp Error."
        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
        Catch Ex As InvalidOperationException
            Email.Dispose()
            Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
        End Try
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Recipients As New List(Of String)
        Recipients.Add("SomeEmailAddress")
        Dim FromEmailAddress As String = Recipients(0)
        Dim Subject As String = "Test From VB."
        Dim Body As String = "email body text, if you are reading this from your gmail account, the program worked."
        Dim UserName As String = "GMAIL USERNAME WITHOUT  (@GMAIL>COM)"
        Dim Password As String = "Password"
        Dim Port As Integer = 587
        Dim Server As String = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Dim Attachments As New List(Of String)
        MsgBox(SendEmail(Recipients, FromEmailAddress, Subject, Body, UserName, Password, Server, Port, Attachments))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am not using form to send the email, i am trying to automate SendMessage from filesystemwatcher when ever FileCreated

Comment: Just modify the code however you need to for it to work with your app. It isn't made exclusively for forms.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from a look at the [MSDN documentation for Outlook 2013's `MailItem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861252.aspx), it appears that there is no `Priority` property (which you're trying to set). Try setting [the `Importance` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866759.aspx) instead.

… or if you don't need Outlook functionality, and just want to send mail, simply use .NET's own [`SmtpClient` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send mail.